# run sbt command for subprojects / set every command from Plugin?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager, sbt-plugin

I found the an [SBT-recipe for parameters and Build Environment](https://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/package_configuration.html).

I would now like to be able to change `buildEnv` while running SBT. Basically

I can't manage to find a programmatic solution for:

`> set every buildEnv := BuildEnvPlugin.autoImport.BuildEnv.Development` or running `BuiltinCommands.set` from a wrapping command.

My basic solution doesn't scale to sub-/aggregated projects 

    `val devCmd = Command.command("dev"){ state =>
     Project extract state appendWithSession (Seq(buildEnv := BuildEnv.Development), state)
    }`

**How can I change all aggregated settings as well?**

Answer (score 0):

I just didn't find this simple solution initially:

```
override def projectSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = commands += devCmd
lazy val devCmd = BasicCommands
    .newAlias("dev", "set every buildEnv := BuildEnvPlugin.autoImport.BuildEnv.Development")
```